# silverlight quote character in textblock

Tags: silverlight, text, formatting

I am trying to create a textblock with oversized quotes at the start and end of some text, which I've managed to do with the following xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBlock Text="&quot;" FontSize="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350">
      This is some text to be quoted!
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Text="&quot;" FontSize="56" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</StackPanel>
```

But what I'd really like is for the quote characters to be curved in towards the text, rather than just the straight up and down variety quotes.  Is there any way to do this without an image for the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Unicode value for single and double curly quotes will help you:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBlock Text="&quot;" FontSize="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350">
      &#8220;This is some text to be quoted!&#8221;
      or      
      &#8216;This is some text to be quoted!&#8217;
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Text="&quot;" FontSize="56" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Those are the regular quote characters; curly quotes are more deliberate and specialized for start and end of text.

Comment: Try using the zoom function on your browser ;)

Comment: interesting... so the unicode values work ok... also copying and pasting the curly quotes in transforms them to straight up and down quotes, but if you hit ctrl-z once, it turns them back into unicode characters that do work.